# Supermicro server not booting with OS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, supermicro

We have purchased Supermicro X9DRi-LN4F model and installed Ubuntu 18 and during installation it finds the HDD and created partition and all goes well, but as soon as installation finishes and it restarts the system it comes up with following error

[image: supermicro_not_booting_os]

What I have done so far:

- Thought may be it is OS corrupt or something so I tried Ubuntu 16 but same issue, also tried Windows 10 but same issue
- Changed Legacy mode from BIOS Advanced > PCIe/PCI/PnP Configuration to UEFI
  but same issue
- Tried to install from UEFI mode but same issue
- Changed the boot order to make sure all is disabled and only HDD is first priority but same issue
- Make sure that BIOS is latest but same issue
- Unplug the HDD and re-plug it back in but same issue

Comment: What HBA are the drives plugged into?

Comment: @MichaelHamptonthere is only one drive which is plugged into HBA.

Comment: Hm. You should wait until you get the rest of your drives, then make sure UEFI is enabled and start the installation again.